# Decreasing the amount of space Ubuntu takes up on a flash drive

Tags: usb-drive, disk-usage

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 on a flash drive; I ended up successful in doing so, however, I was wondering if I could  decrease the amount of space that Ubuntu takes up, since I only seem to have 3.1 GB left on a flash drive that contains 8 GB. Would that be possible, and if I had to partition it, what way should I do so? (Sorry, I'm very new to Linux...)

Comment: You can simply uninstall packages you are not going to use.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 reached end-of-life in February. You should install a newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the fact that 15.04 is unsupported at this point, it has a minimum disk space requirement of 5 GB ([Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Desktop_Edition)). If you need to work under such tight space requirements you should consider to either

- install Ubuntu on a larger medium,
- install a flavour of Ubuntu with a smaller storage footprint (see for example [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](/q/206407/175814)), or
- store some of the programs and user data on a different storage medium.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!